# How to stop certain pages appearing in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I need to add a couple of pages at the front of my report that should not appear in the table of contents.

What is the best way to do this?

I thought that maybe I could write the section normally using \section etc and then remove it from the TOC manually? If so how can I remove it.

Another option would be to dispense with the \section command so that TOC has nothing to find. But the problem then is how to I ensure the header used on that page is consistent with the rest of the document?

Baz

Comment: You want those `\section`s to be numbered or numberless?

Comment: `\section*{This should not appear}` will not appear

Comment: Yes those sections should be numberless and I don't want the section name to appear in the TOC

Comment: @Bazman: Then always use the *starred* version of the corresponding structuring command, i.e. `\section*{Your section title}` but this will lead to unnumbered sections in the text too!

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: the document class is important -- `amsart`, for one, *does* include starred sections in the toc (but there is a method for ignoring them if one needs to).  so please provide that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments mention, use the starred version of `\section`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Appears!}
\section*{Won't Appear}
\section{Appears!}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]